# Starcluster tab completion not working

Tags: bash, starcluster

I am trying to get StarCluster's tab completion to work. Quoting the documentation:

> to enable StarCluster bash-completion support for every shell you
>   open, add the following line to your ~/.bashrc file:

```
source /path/to/starcluster/completion/starcluster-completion.sh
```

But I can not find the script file anywhere. I searched my machine, and I also search the starcluster github project. I can't find it anywhere.

Where is the file located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may simply need to create the file.

`~/.bashrc` is run whenever you start a shell, and provides user-specific customization of your shell environment. It lives in your home directory, so every user can have a (different) one. That is to say, until you start customizing your shell environment, your `~/.bashrc` is probably empty, if it exists at all.

The no-brainer way to do this would be:

```
echo "source /path/to/starcluster/completion/starcluster-completion.sh" >> ~./bashrc
```

This will append the line to the end of your `~/.bashrc`, and create the file if it doesn't already exist. Otherwise you can create a file with your favorite text editor and put the line in it.

EDIT: The OP's problem was not appending to $PATH. It was in finding the starcluster-completion.sh script in order to source it.

You can find the starcluster-completion.sh script here:
https://github.com/jtriley/StarCluster/blob/develop/completion/starcluster-completion.sh

Comment: I think I might have been unclear. I know where and hoe to edit the .bashrc file. I can't find the starcluster-completion.sh file. It is not in my installation of starcluster, and not on the starcluster github repository.

Comment: @Yair: apologies, misread and thought 'where is the script' meant `.bashrc` . Anyway here you go: https://github.com/jtriley/StarCluster/blob/develop/completion/starcluster-completion.sh